# To what value does the sequence $\frac{8^n}{n!}$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

We know that the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ defined by $$a_n=\frac{8^n}{n!}$$ is Decreasing sequence and bounded from below. By Monotone convergence theorem(MCT) it is convergent to its infimum.
Now the author in this pdf says that the sequence is bounded below by zero, but we cannot conclude that it converges to zero.(Page 4)

[https://www.math.drexel.edu/~prs49/ewExternalFiles/Monotone.pdf](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Eprs49/ewExternalFiles/Monotone.pdf)

Is it not evident that it converges to zero as it is an infimum?

Wiki says,  Informally, the theorems state that if a sequence is increasing and bounded above by a supremum, then the sequence will converge to the supremum; in the same way, if a sequence is decreasing and is bounded below by an infimum, it will converge to the infimum.

Why the word informally used? Is the proof of this still pending?

Comment: it is also bounded by  $-1$ and $-2$ and $-5$

Comment: It is evident. It's simply not implied by the theorem.

Comment: @Yorch but they are not greatest lower bounds right?

Comment: Using MCT, you have established that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n = \alpha$ exists. Now, assume $\alpha\ne 0$ , then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{8}{n+1}\to0, n\to\infty$$
But $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to\frac{\alpha}{\alpha}=1, n\to\infty$, which is a contradiction. So, $\alpha = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

You can (since it's obviously true), but just because it's easy to see that it's bounded below by $0$, you also need a proof that it's not bounded below some bigger number (equivalently in this case, you need to also prove that it gets arbitrarily close to 0), to see 0 really is it's infimum.

There are ways to do that (for instance this is easy to bound above by a geometric series, looking at ratios of consecutive terms), but the author is point out that just knowing it's bounded below by 0 is not enough. After all, it's also bounded below by $-1$. You need more to get the proof.

Answer (score 3):

This sequence indeed converges to $0$.

However, the theorem doesn't tell us so.

This is to prevent false conclusion such as this sequence is bounded below by a lower bound and then we immediately conclude that that is a limit.

Comment: So you mean to say that we need to exclusively prove that, zero is the infimum and therefore it converges to zero.Also Wikipedia says, if a sequence is decreasing and bounded below, infimum is the limit.

Comment: yup, we still need to prove that.

Answer (score 1):

Proof that sequence converges to $0$.

Clearly, the sequence will always be positive.

Further, you know that the sequence converges to a limit.

Therefore, if the sequence doesn't converge to $0$, then it must converge to some **fixed** positive limit $L$.

However, as $n \to \infty$, it is clear that $n!$ > $(16^n)$.  Therefore, as $n \to \infty$, the sequence will always be $< \frac{8^n}{16^n} = \frac{1}{2^n}.$

Clearly, $\frac{1}{2^n}$ goes to $0$, as $n \to \infty$.  So, by the **squeeze theorem**, so does $a_n$.